# How to get all info about start date to end date within a given date range?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Recently I've been developing a leave management system. In this application I need a report like in a month wise employee leave statement.

So here's my sample table:

```html
Employee Id application Date Start Date End Date
20130002 14-Mar-2016        16-Mar-2016 17-Mar-2016
20130012 15-Mar-2016        29-Mar-2016 2-Apr-2016
20130003 14-Mar-2016        15-Mar-2016 16-Mar-2016
20130005 10-Mar-2016        24-Mar-2016 24-Mar-2016
20130002 10-Mar-2016        20-Mar-2016 25-Mar-2016
20130006 13-Mar-2016        8-Mar-2016 17-Mar-2016
20130001 14-Mar-2016        4-Apr-2016 24-Apr-2016
20130003 15-Mar-2016        16-May-2016 18-May-2016
20130011 10-Mar-2016        7-Jun-2016 7-Jun-2016
```

Now I need a report where I can get month wise this report. Suppose I need only March's data, like this:

```html
<pre>
Employee Id application Date Start Date End Date 
20130002 14-Mar-2016  16-Mar-2016 17-Mar-2016
20130012 15-Mar-2016        29-Mar-2016 31-Mar-2016
20130003 14-Mar-2016        15-Mar-2016 16-Mar-2016 
20130005 10-Mar-2016        24-Mar-2016 24-Mar-2016 
20130002 10-Mar-2016        20-Mar-2016 25-Mar-2016 
20130006 13-Mar-2016        8-Mar-2016 17-Mar-2016
</pre>
```

How can I achieve this - by PL/SQL or any SQL language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the time component of the dates is set to `00:00:00` then:

```
SELECT EmployeeId,
       application_date,
       GREATEST( start_date, DATE '2016-03-01' ) AS start_date,
       LEAST( end_date, DATE '2016-03-31' ) AS end_date
FROM   table_name
WHERE  Start_date <= DATE '2016-03-31'
AND    end_date   >= DATE '2016-03-01'
```

You can use a bind variable to replace the hard-coded dates like this:

```
SELECT EmployeeId,
       application_date,
       GREATEST( start_date, :month_start ) AS start_date,
       LEAST( end_date, LAST_DAY( :month_start ) ) AS end_date
FROM   table_name
WHERE  Start_date <= LAST_DAY( :month_start )
AND    end_date   >= :month_start
```

If you have time components then:

```
SELECT EmployeeId,
       application_date,
       GREATEST( start_date, :month_start ) AS start_date,
       LEAST( end_date, :month_start + INTERVAL '1' MONTH - INTERVAL '1' SECOND )
         AS end_date
FROM   table_name
WHERE  Start_date <  :month_start + INTERVAL '1' MONTH
AND    end_date   >= :month_start
```

Comment: what is a bind variable

Comment: @sql_dummy A [quick search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=oracle+bind+variable) would provide many answers to that quesiton.

Answer (score 1):

This is for SQL Server

```
SELECT *
FROM    Leaves
WHERE MONTH(StartDate) <= 4 and Month(EndDate) >= 4
```

For Oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM    Leaves
WHERE EXTRACT(month FROM StartDate) <= 4 and EXTRACT(month FROM EndDate) >= 4
```

Comment: This errors with `ORA-00904: "MONTH": invalid identifier`.

Comment: What if the person is on leave for 6 weeks from the last week of March to the first week of May and neither `start_date` nor `end_date` is in April? (or if only one date is in that month)

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be

```
WHERE StartDate>='01-Mar-2016' and EndDate <'01-Apr-2016'
```

Comment: What if the person is on leave for 6 weeks from the last week of February to the first week of April?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parameter for the required month in format 'YYYYMM' (for March 2016: '201603')

then the where-clause would be:

```
where parameter = to_char(start_date,'yyyymm')
or parameter = to_char(end_date,'yyyymm')
```

if a leave can be longer than a month then you also need to check if the parameter is between start and end date.

```
..
or parameter between to_char(start_date,'yyyymm') and to_char(end_date,'yyyymm')
```

to display the correct date in the report you can use a CASE statement combined with the first_day and last_day function to display the first and the last day of the month.
(here the parameter_date is the required month as a DATE, not a VARCHAR2)

```
CASE
    WHEN start_date < first_day(parameter_date) THEN first_day(parameter_date)
    ELSE start_date
END as start_Date,
CASE
    WHEN end_date > last_day(parameter_date) THEN last_day(parameter_date)
    ELSE end_date
END as end_Date
```